# difference between mongodb.so and mongo.so

Tags: php, mongodb

I noticed that the Mongodb driver installation doc shows different extension name for Mongodb driver:

`extension=mongo.so`; another one shows `extension=mongodb.so` -- what's the difference?

http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb.installation.manual.php

Comment: it's just a filename. you could compile the php mongo module and call it "your_mama.so", and it'd still provide mongo functions to php...

Answer (score 4):

`mongo.so` is the filename for the deprecated Mongo PHP extension, `mongodb.so` is the filename for the newer Mongodb PHP extension.

Be wary of any guides referencing the extension without the `db` bit - they are likely referring to the deprecated extension and could well be incorrect.

Comment: I assume that the downvote I received is because in theory the filename could be anything and doesn't make a difference - but seeing as guides and howtos are likely to be using pre-compiled packages then the names will be set by those packages.